# Redirect to hash URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, redirect

I'm building a site with a hashchange on wordpress, all working good. It just loads a single.php template file into a div.

The problem is that i can still access my single url (http://www.mydomain.com/my-single-post). Since its not having any head and style tags with it, i don't want people to go over there. Also google has picked up the direct links, because I use the href attribute to load content into the div.

So my question is:

If someone clicks a link lets say in a forum, http://www.mydomain.com/my-single-post , is it possible to redirect him instantly to http://www.mydomain.com/#my-single-post ? I have researched that it has something to do with .htaccess, but I also have Pages, where i don't want the hash infront of the page-name.

### EDIT

I have a small update. If this code removes the hash-tag from the url and redirects to a non-hash url, then how to put this code in reverse?

```
var current_hash = location.hash;
        current_hash = current_hash.replace(/#/,'');
    if(current_hash.length>1){
        // we have something after the #. redirect as if the # wasn't there.
        window.location.href=current_hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after some trial & error I managed it myself!

This is what I was after:

```
  // If there's a hash in the URL, do nothing
  if(window.location.hash) {

  } else {
  // If there isn't a '#' sign in the URL, add one, and redirect to the hash URL.
    var path = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
     window.location.replace('http://' + top.location.host + '#' + path);
  }
```

There's probably other ways of doing this also, ie. no need for a if / else statement, just to only check if there is a hash.

Comment: Hi @r1987, I think I have a quite similar problem but I'm not using hash URls. I've read that there is no need of it with WP, so I use clean URl and update them with `.pushState`. But now if I hit f5, the single.php becomes visible. Do you have a workaround to prevent it in my case? I'd appreciated if you can help. Here is my thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76257/24778

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Wordpress, but doesn't it come with a built-in tool for configuring your desired URL-format for you posts? My first place to look would be there, and setup a format that match your need with a hash-sign in the URL.

Your other alternative would be to maintain your own htaccess, but since you have some pages at the root that should be redirected to a URL with a hash-sign, and some shouldn't, you would have to create a rule for each page manually I'm afraid, which would be a bit of a pain to maintain in the long run.

I believe this is what Wordpress do behind the scenes for you, which would be much more convenient, but I'n not sure.

Comment: Thats true, you can change the permalink structure in WordPress admin, but for SEO it isn't good idea i think. Jep, so… the rewrite thing wouldn't also go along, because it would be some extra work. But thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do a redirect on your my-single-post page using PHP header if the request is not AJAX. you can pass an AJAX variable as well in your get request to the my-single-post

```
<?php

if($_GET["ajaxVar"]!=1){
header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/#my-single-post");
}
?>
```

Comment: This basically works, allthough i have one big function for click, load and hashchange so this crashes the page, when viewed on the front-page. What i had in mind that, is there may-be a javascript or jquery way to check if location.hash has a # sign inside of it and redirect (or don't do anything) to the #page.